# Not able to insert a row in a table which has auto incremented primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table reportFilters which has the following column names:

[image]

The reportFilterId is auto increment. I want to insert a row in the table with the script below:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'ReportFilters', N'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [ReportFilters]
                    WHERE ReportId IN (SELECT ReportId FROM [Reports] WHERE ReportType = 'Operational Insights Command Staff Dashboard') )
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [ReportFilters] Values(1, 'SelectView', 'Select Views', 13, 'Views','Views', 'SelectView', 'a', 'b', 'c' );
    END
END
GO
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
```

Can I please get help on this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should not get that error unless what you describe is not what is in your database. Or maybe `reportFilterId` is not an identity column. Please provide [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: your picture doesn't show that the ReportFilterID is an IDENTITY. If it isn't, then the syntax you use will expect 11 columns. For several reasons, it is better to explicitly list the columns for which you provide the VALUES in your INSERT statement. See D-Shih's example

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is on inserted columns can't match with inserted data because that will instead by your table column order which is `ReportFilterId` instead of `ReportId`

So that there are 11 columns in your table but your statement only provides 10 columns.

I would use explicitly specify for inserted columns (inserted columns start from `ReportId` except your PK `ReportFilterId` column)

```
INSERT INTO [ReportFilters] (ReportId,ReportFilterName,ReportFilterTitle....)
 Values (1, 'SelectView', 'Select Views', 13, 'Views','Views', 'SelectView', 'a', 'b', 'c' );
```